# The Sourcecode Does not work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This code doesn't work and I don't know why. What error can you find?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>





    </head>         <script src="C:\Users\jsorling\Desktop\test\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\npm.js"></script>      

<body>


<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle"
       data-toggle="collapse"
       data-parent="#accordion2"
       href="#collapseOne">Open!</a> </div> <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well well-small">
            <div class="accordion-toggle">
                ...some text...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2"></div>                             </div>

<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle"
       data-toggle="collapse"
       data-parent="#accordion2"
       href="#collapseOne">Open!</a> </div> <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well well-small">
            <div class="accordion-toggle">
                ...some text...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2"></div>                             </div>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    ...
    <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-heading"></div>
    ...
    <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-heading"></div>
    ...
    <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-heading"></div> </div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    ...
    <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-heading"></div>
    ...
    <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-heading"></div>
    ...
    <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-heading"></div> </div>


<div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a name="Alink1" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
            <strong>Title</strong>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             some random content
            <div>
          </div>  </div>  <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a name="Alink2" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
            <strong>Title 2</strong>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             some random content 2
            <div>
          </div>  </div>


</body> </html>
```

Comment: what doesn't work and what do you expect to happen

Comment: What are you trying to do and why does it not work? What relevance does the windows explorer screenshot have?

Comment: Try placing jQuery `<script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>` before bootstrap `<script src="C:\Users\jsorling\Desktop\test\bootstrap.min.js"></script>` , moving both with `<script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\npm.js"></script>` below above two into `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: More information provide better understand of my situation. The source code works perfectly.

Comment: @HelloWorld See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The path of css and js are causing the error.and load jquery first.change the src of javascript and href of css.
like

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head> 
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="npm.js"></script>          
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

guest271314 has the answer.

```
Try placing jQuery <script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> before bootstrap <script src="C:\Users\jsorling\Desktop\test\bootstrap.min.js"></script> , moving both with <script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\npm.js"></script> below above two into <head></head> tag
```

Comment: You are welcome:) Believe can mark own Answer as "Accepted" ; see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ; or "close" Question ?